# Bluemix, Connection refused after few succeeded connections

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I developing a RESTful application in Bluemix. When I start my application and send @GET request to JAX-RS service it works ok few first requests, but after a while it begins returning an error. After I seen the logs, I found this error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-438, SQLSTATE=42502,
>   SQLERRMC=Connection refused, DRIVER=3.57.82

This is code which I use to get the connection, and of course I close it after I've done my job.

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject vcap_services_obj = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            String driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String icap_services_string = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
            if(icap_services_string == null){
                icap_services_string = FileProvider.readFile("db.ini");
            }
            if (null != icap_services_string && icap_services_string.length() > 0) {
                 vcap_services_obj = gson.fromJson(icap_services_string, JsonObject.class);
            } 
            if (null != vcap_services_obj) {
                JsonArray vcap_services_array = vcap_services_obj.getAsJsonArray("sqldb");

                JsonObject first_db2 = vcap_services_array.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                JsonObject first_credential = first_db2.get("credentials").getAsJsonObject();       

                String host = first_credential.get("host").getAsString();
                String port = first_credential.get("port").getAsString();
                String uid = first_credential.get("username").getAsString();
                String pwd = first_credential.get("password").getAsString();
                String dbname = first_credential.get("db").getAsString();

                String dburl = "jdbc:db2:"+"//" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname;
                try {
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, uid, pwd);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return conn;
```

What can cause to this behavior? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
*The problem was that I was opening connections from another methods and haven't closed them. Thank you to **Jeeva T** for him help.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which plan are you using? I don't see the close connection in the snippet. Btw, did you know that you can get your entire connection string from your vcap(no need to construct it)?

Comment: I'm using Free Plan. My workflow is following, get connection by using the code above. Perform required SQL queries and then close connection from the method which requested this connection. Regarding connection string, yes I seen it but I get this code from example and worked great in another project and I didn't try to optimize it.

Comment: Do you know after how many connections that you're getting the error? The free plan is limited to 10 connections. If you can continuously reproduce it after failing X number of times, there might be something going on with the close. Have you tried logging every close? The standard open/close functions are asynchronous. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db. You may want to give the sync functions a try.

Comment: It's much less than 10 connections, it's like 2-3 connections.

Comment: I checked your connections and you currently have 9 connections opened. All are on UOW Waiting. You may have some idle apps running that haven't closed the connections.

Comment: Hmmm.... it looks very strange. Actually I have only single app with very straight forward code. My `close` statement in a `finally` block so even if an exception is thrown it should be closed. I'll check my code once again. Thank you.

Comment: @JeevaT, I'd added `Sysout` to code which open connection and close and it looks that every time I call to **JAX-RS** service it open connections three times but close it only once. Can't imagine what could be the reason, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I found the error. I intended to open my connection only once and then pass it to methods which perform sequence of queries and the close it. But in every to which I passed connection remained line of code which get connection too but doesn't get closed.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should try to reuse your connections. You should use a ConnectionPool for sharing connections. To debug your open connections, keep a static counter which you increment when you grab a connect, and decrement when you close. You can output a dumpStack whenever a connection is requested. Keep in mind that if you have multiple instances of your application, you will run out of connections even faster.